# To find E(X|Y=y)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am having difficulty to solve the following problem to compute E(X|Y=y)

Question:
Let (X,Y) have joint mass function
$$
\begin{align}
p(k,n)= \frac{C.2^{-k}}{n} \\ 
\end{align}
$$
for k=1,2,... and n= 1,2,...,k

This is how I have tried so far..

1) To find P(Y=y)
$$
\begin{align}
P(Y=y) &= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{C.2^{-x}}{y}\\
&= \frac{C}{y} \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2}^x \\
&= \frac{C}{y} . 1 \\
&= \frac{C}{y}
\end{align}
$$

2) To find P(x|y)
$$
\begin{align}
P(x|y) &= \frac{P(x,y)}{P(Y=y)}\\
&= \frac{C. 2^ {-x} y}{y  C}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}^{x}  \\
\end{align}
$$

3) To calculate E(X|Y=y) by definition,

$$
\begin{align}
E(X|Y=y) &= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{1}{2}^{x}\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{1}{2}^{x}\\
&= 2\\
\end{align}
$$

Not sure whether I did correctly or not. For your advise please.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider the support when computing the marginal pmf of $Y$.

Comment: can you help me how? I am a bit lost. Thanks

Comment: In my step 1), Marginal pmf of Y is summation of all x for joint mass function of (X,Y). Please correct me if my understanding is not correct.
Thanks

Comment: Well, the first thing to notice is that the marginal pmf of $Y$ you have is not even summable (unless your support is finite). Since it's given that $n \leq k$, I'm thinking you need to sum over $x \geq y$ to get the marginal of $Y$.